# ASP.NET MVC 3 books plans

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Does anybody know when first ASP.NET MVC 3 books will come out? I know it is kind of early to ask but I'm wondering if there are some release dates from Apress, Wrox or any other publisher.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**Pro ASP.NET MVC 3 Framework (Apress)** is being written at the moment. Adam Freeman is the primary author; I am the technical reviewer.

I would expect it to be available late Summer 2011, though it's still too early to predict accurately.

Comment: @Steven: In MVC 2 you used Linq to Sql. Will you use EF in MVC 3?

Comment: @Steven Sanderson - dude! i've bought your MVC2 book .. love it :) Will this mean this book will be the next installment in this series? Before, you were the primary author...

Comment: @Steven. I'm glad you've got a co-author for this one. I've been working thru your MVC2 book, and love it, but I keep thinking - how can one person do all this research, and write such a great book by himself? You seem to never slip up, and miss no detail which might cause unexpected problems. Great work!

Comment: Apress has this available via its Alpha program. It allows early access to the eBook.

Comment: Amazon.ca, and amazon.com say it will be released on April 29, 2011

Comment: Steve Sanderson, Pro asp.net mvc master on 246 rep. :) Proves he has no questions to ask =:)

Comment: can anyone tell where can i find db scripts for mvccstore application accompanying the book?

Comment: This is indeed the best MVC book out there.

Answer (score 8):

Go to amazon, search for `asp.net mvc`, then sort by publication date - [like this](http://www.amazon.com/gp/search/ref=sr_nr_scat_283155_ln?rh=n:283155,k%3aasp.net+mvc+3&keywords=asp.net+mvc+3&ie=UTF8&qid=1289324444&scn=283155&h=6627d4e41a3324664b994322fce156ec5681e32a#%2Fref%3Dsr_st%3Fkeywords%3Dasp.net%2Bmvc%26qid%3D1289324494%26rh%3Dn%253A283155%252Ck%253Aasp.net%2Bmvc%26sort%3Ddaterank&enc=1).

Comment: heh) cool feature! never used amazon for this kind of things. really nice trick!

Answer (score 4):

This book is available now as an eBook:

[Pro ASP.NET MVC 3 Framework 3rd Edition](http://www.apress.com/9781430234043)

It is in "alpha" which means you can download what it currently available (775 pages--only a couple chapters unfinished) now, and download the full version when it is finished.

I purchased it and it is an EXCELLENT text!